# Pre-requisites of Magento Learning

Tags: mvc

I've been diving into Magento for last 3 months. I've understood pretty much the app/design-- part of it. But now when i try to look into module development, that look like a really scary part. I've gone through some good articles on module development basics, and have got some surface idea of that, but still when i see code like this, I get blank.

```
public function viewAction()
{
    if ($product = $this->_initProduct()) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_controller_product_view', array('product'=>$product));

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('options')) {
            $notice = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSpecifyOptionMessage();
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addNotice($notice);
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->setLastViewedProductId($product->getId());
        Mage::getModel('catalog/design')->applyDesign($product, Mage_Catalog_Model_Design::APPLY_FOR_PRODUCT);

        $this->_initProductLayout($product);
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('tag/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

I've a decent knowledge of PHP. But I don't have much understanding of MVC frameworks. Should I keep on digging into module development, or should i first learn MVC frameworks like Zend, and then come to magento. Is that step really required?

Comment: Not worth an answer on its own — but I feel my original MVC series is a soft introduction to the concept of MVC development that'll form a nice basis for anyone trying to learn Magento http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_for_php_developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a good understanding of OOP and maybe a basic knowledge of MVC might come in handy. But in this case I would suggest find a good book about Magento programming to get better knowledge of how it works

Comment: Any good book you can recommend?

Comment: http://www.apress.com/9781430272298/ or 
http://www.phparch.com/books/phparchitects-guide-to-programming-with-magento/ or http://www.packtpub.com/magento-php-developers-guide/book and be sure to check out http://alanstorm.com/category/magento